# How to specify discovery docs without triggering consent screen in google calendar?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use google calendar api with scopes:

- `.../auth/calendar.app.created` (*creates secondary calendar and manage it*)
- `.../auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly` (*view calendars*)

It is specified [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#general-verification-process&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-different-types-of-verification-that-google-requires-for-accessing-user-data-via-oauth%2Cwhen-does-my-app-have-to-be-verified-by-google) that google only requires verification if it is:

- app uses any of the sensitive or restricted scopes to request Google User Data
- your application needs to display an icon or display name instead of the redirect URL domain on the OAuth consent screen
- number of authorized domains for your apps exceeds the domain count limit for a project

[image]

Both are non-sensitive scopes (as seen above image), and I'm not using a brand icon so the consent screen app verification should not be shown. Also my OAuth consent screen verification status is not required as seen here:
[image]

Here is my application configuration

```
...

gapi.load('client:auth2');

gapi.client.init({
    clientId: GC_CLIENT_ID,
    apiKey: GC_API_KEY,
    discoveryDocs: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest'
    ],
    scope:
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.app.created https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.calendarlist.readonly'
});

gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3');

...
```

But for some reason, when I try to authenticate to google with my app, the consent screen is still requiring verification:
[image]

Here is the server response to the authentication request:
[image]

Is there something wrong with the discovery docs I'musing? If not, how do I use google calendar without requiring the google app verification even though I'm not requesting sensitive information.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I'm not seeing the `unverified app` screen if I try to authenticate with these scopes (or with any non-sensitive scope, for that matter). Can you provide a set of reproduction steps for this?

Answer (score 0):

Click the advanced button and you will be allowed to continue and authorize your app.

The app will continue to display this message until it has been verified.   Just because you are using non sensitive scopes does not mean that you wont get the not verified app screen.   It just means that when you do go though verification that it will probably be a little quicker since your not using anything declared as restricted or sensitive.

Before you go though the verification process you may find this video helpful [What you need to know about Google verification in 2021.](https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8)

Comment: but why does it say `this app is requesting sensitive information in your google account`? does this mean I still have to verify my app with google?

Comment: You will always have to verify your app with google if it has a consent screen there's no way around that.    Why its showing that its sensitive could be that they have changed something and not update the message.   I would ask them when you go though the process.